# How can i remove large white areas of mobile site?

Tags: css, wrapper, margin, space

I would like to get rid of the large gaps of wasted white space between the two shaded lines for all pages of my mobile site.

Im using `#pageWrapper { margin-top: 30px; }` for the spacing on my desktop version, but maybe this is not the ideal way? I was asked to delete it, but then it messed up the spacing for desktop view.

my site is http://jeffreydowellphotography.com (im sorry if its frowned upon to post my site link, but i dont know how to show you otherwise) I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the mobile styling within a media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #pageWrapper {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
    .sqs-layout .sqs-row .sqs-block:last-child {
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked for the top. How can it affect the bottom spacing?

Comment: I have updated my answer. But in the future you'll just need to look at your DOM and figure out which selectors are applying unwanted white space and adjust accordingly. Just be sure to place the styles within the media query.

Comment: Now it made my two social icons almost touching my copyright text, however it fixed the spacing

Comment: I fixed the social icon thing, but the above css seemed to move the shadow on that thin blue line at the top. What is causing that?

Comment: I wouldn't add the the padding directly to the links since that will increase the clickable area in an unintended manner. Add it directly to .social-links instead.

Comment: Do you know whats making the top drop shadow move away from the line?